# $\sum_{ n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)(3n-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to compute the value of the following sum

> $$\sum_{ n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)(3n-1)}$$

Clearly, it converges since $ \frac{1}{(2n-1)(3n-1)} = O(n^{-2})$. I tried to use the partial fraction decomposition to get : 
$$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(3n-1)}  = \frac{2}{2n-1}- \frac{3}{3n-1}$$

yet, it doesn't seem to lead anywhere since it's hard to see where the terms cancel out. So I don't really know what I could do in order to to attack this sum.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take a look at the properties of digamma function.

Comment: If you just want the answer, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?source=nav&i=sum+from+1+to+infinity+of+1%2F%5B(2n-1)(3n-1)%5D) gives
$$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}+2\log 2-\frac32\log 3$$
But I don't know how that was calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Math-fun commented, this is related to the digamma function
$$S_p=\sum_{ n = 1}^p \frac{1}{(2n-1)(3n-1)}=2\sum_{ n = 1}^p\frac{1}{2n-1}-3\sum_{ n = 1}^p \frac{1}{3n-1}$$
$$S_p=\psi ^{(0)}\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(p+\frac{2}{3}\right)+\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ Now, using the asymptotics
$$S_p=\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{6 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$ and
$$\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-\gamma +\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\gamma -2\log (2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Using they fact that
$$\psi(z+1)-\psi(s+1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+s}-\frac{1}{n+z}$$
Your sum is
$$\psi(2/3)-\psi(1/2)$$
This simplifies to
$$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}-\frac{3\log 3}{2}+2\log 2$$